# Show that $\sin z$ en $\cos z$ are analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $\sin z$ en $\cos z$ are analytic.

To clarify, in my book, they say that analytic means that you can write it as a power series centered at any abritray $a \in \mathbb {C}$. It is not proven yet that differentiable means analytic. I can proof that $e^z$ is analytic using:

$e^z=e^{a+(z-a)}=\sum e^a(z-a)^n/n!$

But I don't see how I can write $\sin z, \cos z$ in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (z-a)^n$.

Comment: You can write them as power series centred at $0$. Use the addition theorem to write $\sin (a+(z-a))$ as a power series centred at $a$.

Comment: $\cos z = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$. There's a similar formula for $\sin z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks !